# How to change indicator style of the current editor window in IntelliJ or WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

By default, currently opened editor window is indicated via underscoring its name on the editor window navigation tab on tap in IntelliJ (or WebStorm).

How can I change indication style from underscoring to something else, for example highlighting the current tab, etc. ?

**P.S.** I am talking about changing indication styling of the place in red eclipse in the pic.

[image]

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I can highly recommend NOT using tabs. Make use of the shortcuts to switch files, which in my experience is way more productive than using tabs.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131683#comment=27-2112280.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you for your comment. It seems the configuration option is not available yet.

Comment: It's available via Ctrl+Alt+Shift+/.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Nothing happens when I hit that key combination in Mac. Is it for Windows?

Comment: Help | Find Action, type Registry.